# Single print statement during loop iteration in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working on a Django template, and I need to print my statement once during the loop iteration. I've tried `{% ifchanged %}`, but it's not working inside two loops.

Using `{% ifchanged %}` works under a single loop, but I am trying this inside two loops.

For example:

```
{% for i in j %}
    {% for k in j %}
        {% ifchanged %}
            //something here//
        {% endifchanged %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, in this case it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

There’s also `forloop.first`.

See [the Django Built-in template tags and filters documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for the variables associated with forloops.

```
{% if forloop.first %}
    // something here //
{% endif %}
```

There is also a `forloop.last`, if it needs to show up at the end, and a `forloop.counter`.